# git is slow on my vagrant centos machine

Tags: git, vagrant, centos6

I'm running vagrant CentOS machine on my Mac. For some reason git takes very long time to respond. For example `git status` takes 2 minutes to respond. Please advise what might be the issue.
Here is my setup

- CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
- git version 2.0.4
- Vagrant 1.8.1
- MacBook Pro OS X El Capitan

Comment: how large is the repo? Does it take that long for `git init` on a new directory?

Comment: is it slow also on your host machine or running `git status` for the same repo is much faster - can you give order of magnitude from host to VM to see if its really an issue from the VM

Comment: What type of file system is that repository on?

Comment: @g19fanatic `git init` on a new directory is fairly fast. Here is the size the git directory I'm having issues with. `count: 2225
size: 75844
in-pack: 931185
packs: 36
size-pack: 640631
prune-packable: 75
garbage: 0
size-garbage: 0`

Comment: @Frédéric Henri the host machine is pretty fast. No issues

Comment: @JanZerebecki I'm not sure how can I find out in CentOS terminal. Its basically a directory with a bunch on python, html and image files

Comment: try after a `git gc`. thats a lot of prune-packable objects. I expect it will run much faster after it is gc'd

Comment: In your git working directory execute `df --output=fstype .` to find out the type of filesystem.

Comment: @JanZerebecki I got this df: unrecognized option '--output=fstype'. When I just did df I got this (Sorry not sure how to format this):
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
                     203334512  19457952 173547680  11% /
tmpfs                  2994532    937992   2056540  32% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1               495844     31959    438285   7% /boot
vagrant              487358464 299677412 187681052  62% /vagrant
home_vagrant_code    487358464 299677412 187681052  62% /home/vagrant/code

Comment: @g19fanatic Thanks. This worked for the most part. Now I average 4 seconds

Comment: That option of `df` seems to have been added in a newer version, then the information is only in the output of mount. If you move the repo from an FS that is mounted from the host to one that is not, it should also improve. Vagrant supports different ways of mounting from the host with different speed characteristics, but I think all of them are slower than in-guest regular file systems (though I haven't checked to be sure).

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, your repository has a lot of loose objects. The more loose objects your repository has, the slower it can perform as it transverses them to operate your git commands.

Running a `git gc` will help clean up these loose files and will probably keep your repo moving along much faster than it currently is.

From the [git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc)...

> Users are encouraged to run this task on a regular basis within each
>   repository to maintain good disk space utilization and good operating
>   performance

Answer (score 1):

Vagrant mounts from the host are usually slower than regular in-guest file systems. Different ways of mounting from the host have different performance.

If you move the repo from an FS that is mounted from the host to one that is not, its performance should improve massively.

As pointed out in the comments, one way to reduce how much work git needs to do is to keep the number of loose objects lower by running [git-gc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc). As a workaround to not manually need to run it you can set [gc.auto](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-gcauto) lower by e.g. `git gc.auto 500`. By default `gc.auto` is set to 6700 which is much higher than the number 2225 of loose objects you had in the comments, so on a normal local file system git upstream would expect it to run fast with that many loose objects.